# Using Grunt/Gulp with PHP Framework

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-4, yeoman

So I just started learning Laravel, and I want to build something cool with it. I've been working mostly with frontend development, particularly AngularJS, and started using RequireJS recently.

I like the way [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io) generators set up front-end applications as far as the directory structure, (i.e. `/app`, `/test`, `/dist`) and would like to continue using this structure, but I want to pull it into the overall application. I also like that in most cases, the application uses unbuilt files (particularly JS) for development because it cuts down on waiting for processes.

How can I set up and structure my Laravel (or any other framework) application and templates to use a similar directory/build setup for files? The problem I keep getting stuck on is using unbuilt/uncompressed files for development, as well as a clean separation of my source vs. built front-end files.

Answer (score 0):

Since starting with Laravel I have tried all sorts of Asset Management tools and methods. I ended up using Stolz/Assets, an ultra-simple-to-use assets management PHP library that can be installed with composer. It is not an ideal tool as there are some issues when minifying (particularly CSS.)

Like you though I really needed  neatly compiled and minified js/css assets for production.

After much research I have ended up using Gulp.js after reading this blog post (http://www.abishek.me/using-gulpjs-with-your-laravel-application/). I immediately downloaded and installed Gulp.js and created a gulp file with my own directory structure in it. I was up and running within minutes. I have since gone on to modify my gulp file so it now compiles SASS, minifies and compresses both CSS and JS for production.

I continue to use Stolz/Assets (Asset Management Library for Laravel) for serving up my files but I do not rely on this for any compiling or minification.